# Alpaca API Date (Start, End) Invalid Error with Python for stocks

Tags: python, api, datetime, stock

When I try to generate the **Start ** and **End ** Dates for the API from Today's function and the last business day I get an error

Here is the code:

```
Symbol=“AAPL”
end= datetime.datetime.today()   
date1= end- pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1) 
start=(date1.strftime(’%Y-%m-%d’)) 

Alpaca= api.get_bars(Symbol, TimeFrame.Day, start, end  , 
adjustment=‘raw’).df
```

I get : APIError: invalid start

Comment: Please write your code as ```Your Code``` to make it clear. :)

Comment: SLKM Esraa, I have updated the code above to make it flow better. regards

Comment: It looks to need a tz-naive datetime object (or its string representation). This is not what you're supplying.